# lost env Var definition

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I have a few env var ( JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME)
defined in my macosx, that I want to change, but I can't find where they are defined.

Can you help me?

grep -r "SOME_VAR_NAME" ./.* 
haven't return anything except the history

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which shell you are using. If it's something other than bash or ksh, such as fish, that will affect the answer. Having said that the first place to check is */etc/profile*. There is also the pam_env(8) module which isn't enabled by default but if it is it loads the */etc/environment* file if it exists (note the file name is configurable). It's also possible you aren't directly setting the var in a "dot" file like *~/.profile*. You may have put the vars in some other file that is sourced by your shell's dot files. Similarly, you may be running a program that outputs env var definitions and running that in a shell dot file; e.g., `eval $(init_java.sh)` or some such. The possibilities are almost limitless.